# Is max evals equals to epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm about to train my own model using Tensorflow and Faster R-CNN Inception v2 Model. And here's the config file:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 500
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}
```

is `max_evals` equals to epoch ? if not, where to configure it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its the no. , how many time you want to evaluate your model in the training process
For eg. : if your training loop is for 1000 epochs & your max_evals = 10 , then the code will evaluate the testing data after every 100 epoch during your training.

Comment: Okay... so, if i have 500 images, max evals = 10, and epoch is set to 100, what does this mean ? and, what is different between epoch and global steps ?

Comment: This will evaluate on your test data(500 images) after every 10 epochs